# Animating div upwards inside another div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I just started learning html, css and javascript to do web development. I'm running into a problem that I can't move a div upwards whenever the mouse is hovered over the div that it's located in.

```css
.profile-button {
  background-color: var(--secundairy-dark);
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  margin: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease, border-radius 0.3s;
}

.profile-button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.profile-button:active {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease, border-radius 0.1s ease;
}

.profile-button:hover>div:nth-child(1),
.profile-button:hover>div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<header style="background-color: grey;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;">

  <div class="profile-button" style="overflow: hidden;">

    <div style="height: 30px;
                        width: 43px;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                        transform: translate(13.5px, 43px);">
    </div>

    <div style="width: 30px;
                        height: 30px;
                        border-radius: 20px;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        transform: translate(17.5px, -17px);
                        border-color: green;
                        border-width: 3px;
                        border-style: solid;">
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

I hope my the way I coded this is at least kind of acceptable, I just started 2 days ago so yeah...

I tried to make it move up using margin-top, I don't really know what else I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does work, but maybe don't use inline styling. I reproduced your example using classes all around and it seems to work (although I haven't made any effort to work out what your desired behavior is). Anyway, do try.

```css
.flex-center{display:flex;align-items:center;}
header{height:100px;width:100%;background-color:dodgerblue;color:white;border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;}
.profile-button {
        background-color:red; /*  var(--secundairy-dark)  */
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        margin: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease, border-radius 0.3s; 
    }

    .profile-button:hover {
        transform: scale(1.15);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .profile-button:active {
        transform: scale(1);
        border-radius: 25px;
        transition: transform 0.1s ease, border-radius 0.1s ease;
    }

    .profile-button:hover > div:nth-child(1),
    .profile-button:hover > div:nth-child(2) {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }

.pbSubOne{height:30px;width:43px;background-color:midnightblue;color:yellow;transform: translate(13.5px, 43px); border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px;}

.pbSubTwo{width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:20px;background-color:midnightblue;color:yellow;transform:translate(17.5px,-17px);border-color:blue;border-width:3px;}
```

```html
<header class="flex-center">

        <div class="profile-button" style="overflow: hidden;">
            
            <div class="pbSubOne"></div>

            <div class="pbSubTwo"></div>

        </div>
</header>
```